# Skip a WHERE condition if a @variable is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the below code I don't want the second part of the join condition to be applicable if @selectAll = 1 
(ie and (listMap.dateOfTask between @startDate and @endDate) 
I am using SQL Server.

```
@userId nvarchar(200),
@startDate nvarchar(200),
@endDate nvarchar(200),
@selectAll bit

select 
    *
from tmListMap l
    right join tmTime t
    on 
        l.timeId = t.timeId 
        and (l.dateOfTask between @startDate and @endDate) //Don’t need this condition if @selectAll = 1
```

Comment: If you don't want A to be required when B is true, the obvious thing to do is `A or B`.

Comment: the datatypes for startDate  and endDate  are nvarchar and you are using the between operator?

Comment: [Using `BETWEEN` for date/times is a bad idea](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common). Doubly so if you're not even using date/time types.

Answer (score 2):

@Damien suggested you need a `or` condition like

```
@userId nvarchar(200),
@startDate nvarchar(200),
@endDate nvarchar(200),
@selectAll bit

select 
*
from tmListMap l
right join tmTime t
on 
    l.timeId = t.timeId 
    and ((l.dateOfTask between @startDate and @endDate) or @selectAll=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@userId nvarchar(200),
@startDate nvarchar(200),
@endDate nvarchar(200),
@selectAll bit

select 
    *
from tmListMap l
    right join tmTime t
    on 
        l.timeId = t.timeId 
where @selectAll = 1 or (l.dateOfTask between @startDate and @endDate)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Two options.

Option A as OR clause

```
@startDate date,
@endDate date,
@selectAll bit

select 
  *
from tmListMap l
  right join tmTime t
    on  l.timeId = t.timeId 
WHERE
    (
        l.dateOfTask between @startDate and @endDate and @selectAll = 0
      OR
        @selectAll = 1
    )
```

Option B as UNION ALL

```
@startDate date,
@endDate date,
@selectAll bit

select 
  *
from tmListMap l
  right join tmTime t
    on  l.timeId = t.timeId 
WHERE @selectAll = 0
    and l.dateOfTask between @startDate and @endDate 
UNION ALL
select 
  *
from tmListMap l
  right join tmTime t
    on  l.timeId = t.timeId 
WHERE @selectAll = 1
```

Depends a bit on your data which will be faster. In my experience the UNION ALL scales better. As long as the different parts are absolutely not able to create duplicates.